# Adding coins and Multiplication Game

Tags: proof-verification, arithmetic

I am currently creating a maths game and need a little help.

Inside the Game you can add up coins.

**maximum 1 each**

(1p,2p,5p,10p,20p,50p,£1,£2)

You can also multiply the current sum

**maximum 1 each**

(x2,x3,x5)

The total sum of adding coins and multiplying 
has to equal to a random generated number which is between £10 and £20.(with decimals)

*An example:*
Random Number = £12.22

Answer: [50p] [x2] [£1] [x5] [£2] [20p] [2p]

My Question is: If there is always a solution to a random Generated Number?
If the answer is no then what should be the upper-bound

Thank you

Comment: Well you obviously cannot get higher than (1p+2p+5p+10p+20p+50p+$1+£2)x5=19.40 unless you are allowed to use coins more than once. There are also some lower numbers you cannot get.

Comment: sorry couldn't explain properly. You can also multiply with the number 2 and 3. It doesn't have to be in the end of sum.

Comment: But can you multiply the £2 by *both* 3 and 5?

Comment: for example (1p+2p+5p+10p+20p+50p+£1+£2)x5x3x2 = £116.4 or                        (1p x2 +2p+5p x5 +10p+20p x3 +50p+£1+£2) = £5.75

Comment: But can you multiply the £2 by both 3 and 5? yes you can

Comment: Can you multiply £2 by 5 several times?

Comment: no you can only use the multiplication of x2, x3, x5 once each

Comment: Can you use a coin more than once?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you want to know the value $k$ so that any random number $\le k$ can be achieved?

Comment: no also once each. The multiplication basically multiplies the current some of the coins. That way you can hit most numbers between £10-£20 but I'm not sure if there is a solution for each number

Comment: Almagast. Not true 2 pounds x 3 + 1 pound x 5 = 35 pounds.  And low coins you can't get??? 1p.  That's getable.  Etc.

Comment: The mulitplications just get applied to the running total?

Comment: yes exactly.. right now I'm playing the game I made. My upper-bound is £20 but I'm not sure since I find some of the number really tricky to reach so I was wondering if its even possible to get numbers below it

Comment: I mean numbers like £14.99 for example. How do I know if you can solve this or not? or other numbers that are not easy to calculate given the rules

Comment: Well, this is crappy math be there are 8+ 8*10+8*10*9+....+8*10! possible outcomes.  You can easily write a program to calculate them all and examine the number of ways for each output.

Comment: @TaZlyy So if you arrange each subset of the 8 monetary symbols and the 3 multiplication symbols in every order and then evaluate them all, those are the possibilities. Is that correct? fleablood is correct it is easy to write a program to evaluate every one and see what the possible outcomes are.

Comment: I don't know how to do this. If someone could give me a proof that it doesn't work up to £20 that would be nice. and if possible a different upper-bound

Comment: @almagest yes its correct. you can arrange any way you want with adding coins and multiplying the current sum

Comment: Set up an array with eleven cells.  Each cell is associated and operation: +1p,+2p...,x3, etc.  Write a bunch of nested loops to list every permutation and subpermutation of these 11 cells.  For each list perform the operations in that order.  Record the result and the permutation in a hash table.  Sort the hash table on the monetary results.  Not only will you find which results are not possible it will show you all the ways to find each result. Including shortest and longest.

Comment: Thanks fleablood. I really appreciate your help, but I'm a total beginner when it comes to programming but I will try it for practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a program to scan the possible plays, and the maximum number of actions (add a coin or multiply) required to reach any value in your playing range is $9$, which occurs only twice at $£16.99$ and $£19.99$

All values up to $£40.00$ are also reachable with no more than $10$ actions. The first value to require all $11$ actions is $£41.99$. The lowest value that cannot be reached is $£59.97$, and $£59.99$ is also unreachable.

Comment: oh wow that is awesome... I wrote this code in Java and I was trying to solve the number £15.98 and am struggling. But its good to know that they all work. I would also like to know the first unreachable number as its very interesting. Thank you Joffan

Comment: "Amazingly"?  I'm not surprised.  I'd be interested in which values are easy to reach and which are hard.  I imagine x.99 are generally few ways to reach.

Comment: @TaZlyy £15.98 can be made as 5p, +£1, $\times 5$, +1p, $\times 3$, +20p

Comment: thanks joffan, you helped me alot! +rep